UglifyJS options not being set when trying to set in Flask app using Flask-Assets?
I'm trying to get uglifyJS working in my Flask app using Flask-Assets. I cannot for the life of me figure out why my settings aren't being applied.
I'm basically trying to use UGLIFYJS_EXTRA_ARGS to set these options, as described in the webassets documentation. But only one of the settings were successfully applied, the -m (mangle) option.
I tried the following code in my Flask app:
app = Flask(__name__)
app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# Pack the JS and CSS for obfuscation / optimization.
assets = Environment(app)
app.config['UGLIFYJS_EXTRA_ARGS'] = [
    "-m",  # Mangle the JS
    "-c drop_console=true",  # Drop console.log statements from minified JS (remove for debugging)
    "--beautify preamble='Copyright stuff'",
]
main_js = Bundle(
    (a bunch of script files),
    filters="uglifyjs",
    output="dist/scripts/main_script.min.js"
)
assets.register('main_js', main_js)

I was expecting that the code would be mangled, no console log statements would be included in the minified output, and that there would be a preamble saying "copyright stuff". But only the mangling option seems to be applied to the end result.
